# variables as interpolated string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I've been trying to display a **react-table cell** in a **customized way**:

```
public renderBooksTable() {
        return <div>
            <ReactTable
                data={this.props.books}
                columns={[{
                    columns: [{
                        Cell: row => (
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" id={row.bookid} value={row.bookURL} />
                            </div>
                        )
                    },
...
```

**bookid and bookURL** are coming as **undefined**. Whereas, accessors for other columns are **displaying well**.

Comment: you are missing a backtick like `'`${row.bookid}`'`

Comment: It's hard to say based on just he information you've given, but please verify that `bookid` is not spelled `bookId` OR `bookURL` is not spelled `bookUrl` elsewhere..

Comment: Try logging out the value of `row` object in your `Cell` renderer.

Answer (score 0):

As @mccambridge suggested I tried logging out the value of row and realized that the row.row didn't have bookid and bookurl because I didn't specify them as accessors.

Hence, I had to retrieve them from the _original as shown below:

```
<input type="text" id={row.row._original.bookid} value={row.row._original.bookURL} />
```